# Untrackable deprecation notice

Tags: php, symfony, deprecated

#### Using

- PHP 8.1
- Symfony 5.4

#### Problem

Every symfony command console output is followed by deprecation notice

> 2022-11-23T22:22:33+01:00 [info] Deprecated: ucfirst(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

The problem is I am not using ucfirst anywhere in my project, so it probably is some composer package deprecation. However the deprecation notice does not contain neither the path to a file nor any other clue how it can be found.

How can one track the file / code which triggers this deprecation?

Comment: What do you expect to do if you find it? Are you going to make a local change to Symfony to get rid of the warning? Maybe you should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set `error_reporting=E_ALL` (not mandatory as you have depreciation notice emitted already) and then `log_errors = On` and perhaps `log_error = syslog` and then inspect the log entries in syslog and you should have file and line number which potentially could help you back track the culprit.

Aside from this, it's a depreciation **notice** and not an error. And since it's not in your code, there's not much you can do beside upgrade your dependencies (incl. Symfony) or disabling `E_DEPRECATED` notices from being emitted. Again, this is a notice, not an error.